# Hours and minutes as 5 digit decimal in excel, TSQL

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I pull clinical claims data from a clinic in an excel file format and load the data into SQL server 2008.

Src Date (in excel) : 57957

It's converted into datetime format and loaded into SQL server using following code.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),cast(57957 - 18263 as datetime),101) ==> "09/05/2008"
```

Now the excel has been updated to pull time value in a separate field.

Time : 59400.

How do i convert this decimal value into HH:MM:SS format?

Answer (score 0):

Change the Excel column's data type to DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

59400 probably is the 'decimal' part of the date, if so then:

```
 select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),cast(.59400 as datetime),108)
```